# PHP session based hit counter too trigger-happy

Tags: php, session, session-timeout, hitcounter

I have a simple session-based PHP hit counter on a website. The problem is that it seems to be adding phantom hits whenever I have the website open for some time (even without me reloading it), so I'm thinking the session timeout is set to a very short amount of time somewhere on the server. However, I have checked php.ini and the timeout is the standard 24 minutes, while phantom hits get added every three minutes or so.

The website has no nameservers pointing to it yet, nothing links to it, so it's not an issue of robots/crawlers. Here is my code:

```
            $hit_file = file(__DIR__ . "/hit_file.txt");

            $hit_num = $hit_file[0];
            if(!isset($_SESSION['been']))

                {


                    $hit_num++;

                    $hit_write = fopen(__DIR__ . "/hit_file.txt", 'w');

                    fwrite($hit_write, $hit_num);

                    fclose($hit_write);

                    $_SESSION['been'] = 1;

                }

             echo $hit_num;
```

UPDATE: I have noticed some weird access.log entries. They all follow this format:
::1 - - [06/Nov/2012:22:05:03 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3719 "-" "-"

I get one every five minutes or so which is about how often phantom hits get added. What on earth are they?

Comment: Where's your `session_start()`?  And where is the site located right now?  Why not capture some info about the hit (date, time, IP address) and write that to your log to see what's going on?

Comment: PHP is stateless. Keeping the page open would not trigger additional page hits unless you had AJAX triggering it.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to measure?  Unique user sessions?

Comment: session_start() is at the top of every page, this is just the counter code. And the sessions do start just fine.

Comment: It's not bots. I have checked the access logs. It's just me accessing the site. And yes, I'm trying to measure unique sessions. My logs show a lot of "GET /undefined HTTP/1.1" 404 entries. I do have a jQuery image slider on the site that currently doesn't have anything to show so that's probably the 404s. But can that be triggering hit counter code on my index.php?

Comment: No, 404 are triggered by your webserver, your logentries/index.php is  200 (OK). $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] and $_SERVER[''REMOTE_ADDR'] could help if you have a short session lifetime.

Comment: Okay, what on earth are these entries: ::1 - - [06/Nov/2012:22:05:03 +0100] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 3719 "-" "-"? I get one every five minutes.

Comment: Maybe its some crawling bot? Figure out what the IP address is and do a reverse lookup, could tell you if its from a bot

Comment: That's the weird thing, the entries don't have an IP (see above, that's all I get).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

::1 is localhost IPv6 address. That's where I'd start looking if I were you. One of the apps is making these requests. Either track it down or just make check `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` if it's not ::1.

Answer (score 0):

I would say if you looked at your logs you would see that it is search engine bots (and possibly others) crawling your site. That is, if your site is live at the moment.